# How do i create two visualization on a world map of our cargo flow in logistics over 5 years?

Tags: d3.js, tableau-api

I would like to create two visualization on a world map of our cargo flow over the last five years. One for import and one for export.

Comment: Hi Njema, You probably wont get much of a response to your question. It is too broad and asking for people to reach out to you. This community is designed for very specific questions which can then be _referenced later by others_. I would highly suggest that you, instead of asking for broad help, try to create the visualization yourself and then ask a question once/if you run into specific difficulty. Please reference the nature of other questions (especially those with lots of upvotes) and you will see what is expected.

Comment: Thanks Daniel for your kind response.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like what you want is a geospatial sankey:

- https://github.com/geodesign/spatialsankey
- https://github.com/calocan/rescape-geospatial-sankey

Bear in mind that if the numeric range you're dealing with is large, then the smaller lines will be difficult to see. Also, you'll need to implement [hierarchical edge bundling](https://bl.ocks.org/sjengle/2e58e83685f6d854aa40c7bc546aeb24); otherwise, you'll have lines all over the place, like a tangle of spaghetti.

I did something like this once (except without the edge bundling, which would have made it better):

- https://unfpamaldives.github.io/migration/
- https://github.com/unfpamaldives/migration

Comment: Thanks Passer this means i use d3.js as my  visualization tool.